# ASP.net MVC ViewModel properties are null after submiting form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Before submitting this question I searched a lot and for every question that I read either the situation was not the same or the answer didn't work for me.

As the title says, I have an **MVC ViewModel** as such:

```
public class RetrieveTestResultsViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("نام کاربری")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نام کاربری را وارد کنید")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("شماره تلفن")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا شماره تلفن را وارد کنید")]
    [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "شماره تلفن باید 11 رقمی باشد", MinimumLength = 11)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^0[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "شماره تلفن صحیح نیست")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }


}
```

I made sure that all properties are public and of primitive type (string).

Then inside the **CSHTML form**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Retrieve", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", autocomplete = "off", id = "newsletterForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {

                <div class="row">

                    @*username*@
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-control-custom">
                            @Html.NoAutoCompleteTextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, "input-lg font-size-sm mr-md formal", "نام کاربری *")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    @*phone number*@
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-control-custom">
                            @Html.NoAutoCompleteTextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "input-lg font-size-sm mr-md formal", "شماره تلفن *")
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <button type="button" autocomplete="off"
                                onclick="AjaxForm.CustomSubmit(this, 'newsletterForm')"
                                data-loading-text="در حال ارسال اطلاعات"
                                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block font-size-sm text-uppercase mt-sm formal">
                            دریافت نتایج
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Please note that the custom-made **NoAutoCompleteTextBoxFor** method is well-tested in other projects and it is as bellow:

```
public static MvcHtmlString NoAutoCompleteTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return html.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" });
    }
```

Also at the top of my CSHTML i declared the model:

```
@model VH.ViewModel.TestResults.RetrieveTestResultsViewModel
```

Inside my **Home controller**, there is the **Retrieve POST method**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Retrieve(RetrieveTestResultsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // viewModel.UserId -> null
        // viewModel.PhoneNumber -> null 
    }
```

As you see, Inside the Retrieve method, I put a breakpoint and I see that none of my inputs are binded to viewModel!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the model in your view? @model RetrieveTestResultsViewModel

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: `NoAutoCompleteTextBoxFor` component never worked or only in this view?

Comment: It works in other projects, I also replaced it with the default TextBoxFor , but that didn't work either.

Comment: What does the network-tab of  the devConsole says when you check the network-tab and post the form?

Comment: Adds a green row, "retrieve , Status: 200 OK , type : xhr , initiator: VM31:1 , size: 9 KB" any other things to look for in network-tab?

Comment: Click on the row, a sidebar should open, check form-data

Comment: I just tried it with a simple <button type="submit"> and the model posted without issues. I would suggest you take a look at Ajaxform.CustomSubmit-function.

Comment: strange! There is no FormData, only General, ResponseHeaders and RequestHeaders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184878/discussion-between-sprezlaus-and-ali-jey).

Comment: @Sprezlaus , I changed the form Id and it worked. Can you suggest why It wouldn't before?

Answer (score 0):

You used the **multipart/form-data** for the **enctype** of your form. You can use it when you want to upload some files to your action. But you should decorate your action parameter with **[FormData]** attribute. This will tell **MVC** that your model should be made from the form inputs.
You can remove the **enctype** attribute or use the **FormData** attribute.

```
public ActionResult Retrieve(
     [FormData] RetrieveTestResultsViewModel viewModel)
{

}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Hey Armin. Thank you for your answer. I removed the enctype, but it didn't work. I also tried adding [FormData] Attribute but I don't know in what namespace it is so visual studio gives me error.

Comment: I think that was about your ajax options as you said above

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it.

I changed the form Id to something else and it worked!

If anybody can guess what was wrong please put an answer.

Comment: is there another element on the page with the same id?